# iOS LargeTitle with UISegmentedControl and childViewController (in a Container)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, large-title

I have a `UIViewController` in my app that has a `UISegmentedControl` with three segments. Each one of them is a `UIViewController` that has a `UICollectionView` inside.

When I set the large title to the main `UIViewController`, it shows the large title perfectly, but the problem is that, when I scroll any of the segment's `UICollectionView`, nothing happens to the large title: it does not collapse.

Is there anything special that's needed to be done in that specific scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I've just found what I was doing wrong.
The problem was that the `UIContainerView` that contained the segments' `UIViewControllers` was not the first child.

*Gotta be aware of this logic from now on...*